# Search for a word in a PDF on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, cgpdfdocument

I use `CGPDFDocumentRef` control to view pdf file in iPad. I want to add search capability and highlight the results. Any suggestions on how I can do so? In addition, I would like to know if there there a way to zoom in and out using a multi-touch?

Comment: I am having the same problem.Please suggest me any answer if u have...

Answer (score 1):

following sample has most of the features you need.

https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit